# I am trying to write single subroutine for both word and byte sized array but the code doesn't terminate

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bubble-sort

**How should I write a single code for both byte and word sized array?**
*The code below doesn't terminate for one array being byte sized and the other one being word sized*

> In this code bubble sort algorithm is used to sort 2 arrays named as data and data2 but when I run the code it doesn't terminate and keeps on running.Am I writing the code correctly or there should be changes?

```
[org 0x0100]

jmp start

data: dw 60,40,50,22,5

data2: db 3,4,1,9,6

swapflag: db 0

swap:

mov ax, [bx+si]               
xchg ax, [bx+si+2]            
mov [bx+si], ax               
ret                           

bubblesort: 

dec cx                        
shl cx, 1                     

mainloop: 

mov si, 0                     
mov byte [swapflag], 0        

innerloop: 

mov ax, [bx+si]              
cmp ax, [bx+si+2]            
jbe noswap                    
call swap                     
mov byte [swapflag], 1        

noswap: 

add si, 2                     
cmp si, cx                   
jne innerloop                
cmp byte [swapflag], 1      
je mainloop                 
ret                           

start: 

mov bx, data                 
mov cx, 10                  
call bubblesort              
mov bx, data2              
mov cx, 20                    
call bubblesort              

mov ax, 0x4c00 
             
int 0x21
```

Comment: start by writing code only for one size (for example for byte), make sure it works perfectly, then modify it to support only word size, you will notice that both versions differ by couple instructions only (like +1 vs +2), now introduce additional variable which will tell you which instruction to execute and incorporate it into any version, thus getting universal one

Comment: so you are suggesting to introduce a new variable but how would that variable help in distinguishing between 2 different sizes

Comment: in pseudo code it will look like `if size == 1 compare(bx+si, bx+si+1) else compare(bx+si, bx+si+2)` after that flags will contain comparison result and you can use the same `jbe noswap` for example

Comment: hmm...thanks, I think now I might get to something :-D

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> mov bx, data
> mov cx, 10           <<< 5 elements !!!
> call bubblesort
> mov bx, data2
> mov cx, 20           <<< 5 elements !!!
> call bubblesort
> ```

You are calling the *bubblesort* subroutine with counts that are much too high for the 5-element arrays that you have. This error will process garbage data but does not explain why "it doesn't terminate".

---

The **endless loop** problem exists because, at the conclusion of the *innerloop*, you forget to lower the limit that is held in the CX register. It is by lowering the limit that we indicate that the last element is in its final place, and that we no longer need to consider it, thus reducing the task and working towards an end.

Next is a corrected version of the code. I did not optimize it so you can still recognize the problem and how it was solved.

```
; IN (bx,cx)
bubblesort16: 
  dec  cx                        
  shl  cx, 1               *      
mainloop: 
  mov  si, 0                     
  mov  byte [swapflag], 0        
innerloop: 
  mov  ax, [bx+si]         *    
  cmp  ax, [bx+si+2]       *    
  jbe  noswap                    
swap:                                ;
  xchg ax, [bx+si+2]       *         ; better have this inlined
  mov  [bx+si], ax         *         ;
  mov  byte [swapflag], 1
noswap: 
  add  si, 2               *      
  cmp  si, cx                   
  jne  innerloop                
  cmp  byte [swapflag], 0            ; 
  je   done                          ;
  sub  cx, 2               *         ;  new (solution)
  jnz  mainloop                      ;
done:                                ;
  ret
```

I've marked with an asterisk the lines that need to change for the byte-sized version.

> How should I write a single code for both byte and word sized array?

My first reaction to having a single code that can deal with byte and word arrays alike was that it would make for a slower code due to the extra branches in the innerloop. It turns out this is not the case. I managed to write a dual *Bubblesort* code that fulfills the requirements and that performs on a par with (or even a bit faster than) the corresponding *BubbleSort16* and *BubbleSort8* versions. The suggestions that @PeterCordes gave in comments were very helpful to arrive at this result.
One minor drawback of the dual solution is, that apart from a count and an address, it also requires a 3rd distinctive argument in CX = {1=bytes,2=words}.

```
; --------------------------------------
; IN (ax,bx,cx) OUT () MOD (ax,dx,si,di,bp)
BubbleSort:
        sub  ax, 1          ; Number of elements
        jbe  .Done
        mul  cx
        add  ax, bx         ; -> Address of the last element
        xor  bp, bp         ; SwapFlag [0,1]
.Outer: mov  si, bx
.Inner: mov  dx, [si]
        cmp  cx, 2
        jb   .Byte
.Word:  mov  di, [si+2]
        cmp  dx, di
        jle  .Skip
        mov  [si+2], dx
        mov  [si], di
        mov  bp, 1
.Skip:  add  si, cx         ; CX=[1,2]
        cmp  si, ax
        jb   .Inner
.Both:  dec  bp
        jnz  .Done
        sub  ax, cx         ; CX=[1,2]
        cmp  bx, ax
        jb   .Outer
.Done:  ret

.Byte:  cmp  dl, dh
        jle  .Skip
        rol  dx, 8
        mov  [si], dx
        mov  bp, cx         ; CX=1
        inc  si
        cmp  si, ax
        jb   .Inner
        jmp  .Both
; --------------------------------------
; IN (ax,bx) OUT () MOD (ax,dx,si,bp)
BubbleSort8:
        nop
        nop
        sub  ax, 1          ; Number of elements
        jbe  .Done
        add  ax, bx         ; -> Address of the last element
        xor  bp, bp         ; SwapFlag [0,1]
.Outer: mov  si, bx
.Inner: mov  dx, [si]
        cmp  dl, dh
        jle  .Skip
        rol  dx, 8
        mov  [si], dx
        mov  bp, 1
.Skip:  inc  si
        cmp  si, ax
        jb   .Inner
        dec  bp
        jnz  .Done
        dec  ax
        cmp  bx, ax
        jb   .Outer
.Done:  ret
; --------------------------------------
; IN (ax,bx) OUT () MOD (ax,dx,si,di,bp)
BubbleSort16:
        sub  ax, 1          ; Number of elements
        jbe  .Done
        shl  ax, 1
        add  ax, bx         ; -> Address of the last element
        xor  bp, bp         ; SwapFlag [0,1]
.Outer: mov  si, bx
.Inner: mov  dx, [si]
        mov  di, [si+2]
        cmp  dx, di
        jle  .Skip
        mov  [si+2], dx
        mov  [si], di
        mov  bp, 1
.Skip:  add  si, 2
        cmp  si, ax
        jb   .Inner
        dec  bp
        jnz  .Done
        sub  ax, 2
        cmp  bx, ax
        jb   .Outer
.Done:  ret
; --------------------------------------
```

Measured times on Intel Pentium dual-core T2080:

```
Sorting an array with 46 bytes
------------------------------
BubbleSort    17.2 µsec - 17.3 µsec
BubbleSort8   17.2 µsec - 18.5 µsec

Sorting an array with 23 words
------------------------------
BubbleSort     3.8 µsec -  3.9 µsec
BubbleSort16   4.1 µsec -  4.3 µsec
```

Comment: *so why not make it worse?* - They're already using `xchg`-with-memory, which is an atomic RMW on 386 and later.  So if branches predict well, it's maybe 20x slower than necessary, if not more.  Other fun ways to make it slow include store-forwarding stalls by swapping bytes with `rol word [si-1], 8` as in [Sort an Integer List](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149038) (code golf)

Comment: Interesting.  You're benchmarking on a Core1 (Pentium-M entry in Agner Fog's microarch PDF).  I was going to say that code alignment (especially tops of loops) would be important, but apparently it's not in P-M: a 16-byte IFETCH block after a predicted branch starts at the target instruction, unaligned.  So in general code alignment isn't a big deal, but laying out instructions into decode groups (like 3-1-1) can be.  (Spreading out some of the harder to predict branches may help the predictors, too?  I wonder if that's related to it being faster)

Comment: Note that `xchg dl,dh` will cause a partial-register stall when reading DX; use `rol dx,8` if you care about modern x86 more than 8086 compat or 286 performance.  (Especially your own CPU where partial-reg penalties are bigger than on Sandybridge-family.)  `dec`/`js` can't macro-fuse into a single uop on SnB-family; prefer `dec/jne` to check for it not having been 1 before the -=1.  Your CPU can't macro-fuse even the `cmp`/`jcc`, that feature was new in Core2, so it's not going to affect your timing.

Comment: Your byte sort is causing store-forwarding stalls after every swap since the word reload partially overlaps the last word store.  I'd have worried that the 2-size version would be more likely to have register-read stalls, since you're reading an extra never-changing register, CX.  `mov  dx, [si]` can get hoisted out of the branches, in case that helps.  Also, `add  si, cx` can be done before branching.  Then you might just duplicate the tail of the inner loop for each size, saving a `jmp` for one of them. (Put one of the blocks after the `ret`, and end it with `jb .Inner`, fall through to JMP)

Comment: Your Core1 CPU does rename 16-bit partial registers, unlike Haswell and later or AMD, so it shouldn't have false dependencies all over the place from writing 16-bit registers.  That might cause some slowdown running this on more modern CPUs.

Comment: @PeterCordes My previous measurements were way off because I stupidly had placed the array(s) too near to the code. At a good distance (64 bytes was fine), the code already ran 5 to 7 times faster! I have rewritten my code based on your suggestions for which I thank you, and got a 16% speed increase for the 8-bit sort, and a 22% speed increase for the 16-bit sort. In conclusion, speedwise there's nothing against the dual-size code, but I do find the need for a 3rd argument annoying.

Comment: Heh, SMC pipeline nukes would be a problem, yeah.  These times are even closer to the theoretical 4x ratio you'd predict for an O(N^2) algorithm where there aren't any smaller terms, just 2 nested loops.  And a bit extra from store-forwarding stalls.  The top of `.Inner:` is now 3 uops before the first branch, so that's probably good to maximize front-end throughput in case it's taken.